# Print identify results QGIS

Tags: qgis

I want to print the results of the identify features, I know that there is a way to do it with the Python console, but the thing is that i have to set up an easy approach for one who is not into QGIS or Python. Has anyone an idea or an easy  workaround?

[image]

Comment: Right click layer (Bezeichnum) and select Copy Feature Attributes or just take a screen dump or use a screen snipping tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the QGIS report generator to create a report with all the feature attributes and then print the final report.  You should be able to set this up before giving it to the user.  Also my report repeats for each feature but if you wanted a single feature you could easily filter out a specific feature.

First go to the QGIS menu Project  -> New Report.  Give it any name.

You will now be in the report generator.
[image: report1]

Select the green plus sign and add a new field group section.  Select your layer from the layer drop down.  Turn on the check box to include body and click the edit button.  A layout will be added to your view.  Add a label to the layout
[image: report2]

Edit the label to include the necessary fields.  Click the Insert an expression button.  Go to tthe fields drop down.  Double click one of the fields you would like to add, make sure it is added to the window on the left.  Click Ok.
[image: report3]
[image: report4]
[image: report5]

Repeat "Insert an Expression" for the other fields
[image: report6]

Now your label should have all the attributes.
[image: report7]

Now you should be able to print the report by clicking the print button or export to PDF.

[image: report 8]